# List comprehension, but for dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

A more pythonic way of doing the following? In this example, I'm trying to build comments (a dict) to be key-value pairs where the key is the unmodified-version, and the value is the return value from a function where the key was passed as an arg.

```
def func(word):
    return word[-1:-6:-1].upper()

subs = {
    'ALLOWED': ['one', 'two'],
    'DISALLOWED': ['three', 'four']
}

comments = {}
for sub in subs['ALLOWED']:
    # reverse and uppercase
    comments[sub] = func(sub)

print(comments)
```

Anyone have recommendation? It's not exactly important to have this done, but I love learning python idioms and ways to make my code more pythonic. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) instead of building your dictionary in a `for` loop:

```
comments = {key: func(key) for key in subs['ALLOWED']}
```

Comment: Alternatively, avoiding comprehension for built-ins: `dict(zip(subs['ALLOWED'], map(func, subs['ALLOWED'])))` No, not more Pythonic, just an option. I think I'd prefer the comprehension in real life, which is why this isn't an answer. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger not bad at all. Although it wouldn't make much of a difference for this particular use case, I think your version would perform better than mine (though I haven't tested yet). Although, as you said, certainly not more pythonic ; )

Comment: Yar. My main objection to my "solution" is that it violates DRY (it looks up `'ALLOWED'` twice); for small inputs, yours will definitely win, mine might be a titch faster for huge inputs, but it's likely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the loop and replace it inside the function with a dictionary comprehension. Then, you can simply return it.

Also, you can reverse the string `word` with `[::-1]`, not the complex `[-1:-6:-1]` slice you're using:

```
def func(words):
    return {word: word[::-1].upper() for word in words}
```

This yields the same thing:

```
comments = func(subs['ALLOWED'])
print(comments)
# {'two': 'OWT', 'one': 'ENO'}
```